# Data Visualization of Feature Distribution Plot

Tags: data, visualization, matplotlib, plotting

I have been trying my best to plot this type of feature distribution plot using Python.  I looked for what they are called to replicate the plot, but couldn't find the name of it?
[image]

The Reference of the plot is : 
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13278-016-0358-5